# problema en la creacion de altura de un arbol binario

Tags: c++

lo que sucede es que cree dos funciones para buscar la altura de un nodo dentro de un arbol y que en ella se busque cual es la altura maxima del mismo.

```
int GetAltura(Nodo *aux,int n,int contador){
    if(aux!= NULL){
        if (n != aux->GetIdentificador()) {
            if (n < aux->GetIdentificador() && aux->GetApuntadorIzq() != NULL) {
                aux = aux->GetApuntadorIzq();
                GetLongitudProfundidad(aux, n, contador);
            }
            else {
                if (aux->GetApuntadorDer() != NULL) {
                    aux = aux->GetApuntadorDer();
                    GetLongitudProfundidad(aux, n, contador);
                }
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        }else{
            Comparador(aux,contador,0,0);
            return contador;
        } 
    }
}
```

esta funcion ocupa recursividad y llama a la siguiente funcion.

```
int Comparador(Nodo *aux,int contador,int contIzq,int contDer){
    if(aux->GetApuntadorIzq()!=NULL){
        aux=aux->GetApuntadorIzq();
        Comparador(aux,contador,contIzq,contDer);
        
    }else{
        contIzq++;
        cout<<contIzq;
    }
    if(aux->GetApuntadorDer()!=NULL){
        aux=aux->GetApuntadorDer();
        Comparador(aux,contador,contIzq,contDer);
        
    }else{
        
        contDer++;
        cout<<contder;
    }
    if (contIzq>=contDer)
        contador+=contIzq;
    else
        contador+=contDer;
    return contador;
}
```

mi problema surge que cuenta al auxiliar con el que quiero que empiece como si fuese una hoja y empieza a contar como si el principal fuera la raiz y no el nodo que habia seleccionado.

aqui abajo muestro como se ve el arbol y que solo toma como referencia lo que habia dicho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]